# Transforming the same xsl file in ie9 and ie10 yields different html

Tags: html, xml, xslt, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have XSL code that looks like this...

```
<xsl:template name="doHeader">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
<head>
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="IMPORT">
        namespace="search" implementation="../html/scripts/button.htc"
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("../temp/theme.css");
        @import url("../html/css/view.css");
        @import url("../html/css/search.css");
    </style>
    <script src="../html/scripts/utils.js" />
    <script src="../html/scripts/search.js" />
</head>
</xsl:template>
```

(Of course, I added that meta tag in the ie10 version). Anyway, in the html that is run in ie9, there is code for the button, but in ie10, there's no button code.

ie9 looks like this...

```
<TR><TD>
    <?import namespace = search urn = "_" implementation = "file:///C:/Users/.../button.htc" /><search:button onclick=handleSubmit() value="OK">
    <DIV>
    <DIV style="LINE-HEIGHT: 1px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #a1b8c9; MARGIN: 0px 2px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 1px; FONT-SIZE: 1px">&nbsp;</DIV>
    <DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #a1b8c9 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #a1b8c9 1px solid; LINE-HEIGHT: 1px; MARGIN: 0px 1px; DISPLAY: block; BACKGROUND: #eef5f9; HEIGHT: 1px; FONT-SIZE: 1px; BORDER-TOP: #a1b8c9 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #a1b8c9 1px solid">&nbsp;</DIV>
    <DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #a1b8c9 0px solid; POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: center; BORDER-LEFT: #a1b8c9 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #eef5f9; PADDING-LEFT: 20px; PADDING-RIGHT: 20px; DISPLAY: block; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; BORDER-TOP: #a1b8c9 0px solid; CURSOR: default; BORDER-RIGHT: #a1b8c9 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 4px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" tabIndex=0>
    <DIV>OK</DIV>
    <P style="POSITION: absolute; COLOR: #ff0000; TOP: 5px; LEFT: 35px"></P></DIV>
    <DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #a1b8c9 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #a1b8c9 1px solid; LINE-HEIGHT: 1px; MARGIN: 0px 1px; DISPLAY: block; BACKGROUND: #eef5f9; HEIGHT: 1px; FONT-SIZE: 1px; BORDER-TOP: #a1b8c9 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #a1b8c9 1px solid">&nbsp;</DIV>
    <DIV style="LINE-HEIGHT: 1px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #a1b8c9; MARGIN: 0px 2px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 1px; FONT-SIZE: 1px">&nbsp;</DIV></DIV></search:button>
</TD></TR>
```

but in ie10 it looks like...

```
<TR><TD><search:button onclick=handleSubmit() value="OK"></search:button></TD></TR>
```

What do I need to do to get ie10 to generate the same (ish) html as ie9?

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide *both* results -- in IE9 and in IE10 -- not only the IE9's result. My guess is that you may need to have: `<xsl:processing-instruction name="import">` -- IE10 may be more case-sensitive than IE9.

Comment: I think the `meta` element belongs inside of the `head`, not before it. That could be one potential issue.

Comment: @Dimitre changing the case did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @Martin moving the meta tag inside of `head` did not work either.

Comment: I would try to isolate the problem by first creating a static HTML document using that `htc`. If IE10 does render that as you want then we need to try to make sure that the XSLT output is rendered the same as the static HTML. Currently it is not clear whether the problem is with IE10 not supporting that `htc` use or whether it is an XSLT problem.

Comment: @Martin when I copy and paste that working IE9 code into the html that was generated from the F12 tools with IE10, it does render the button in IE10.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think we can solve that by exchanging comments on Stackoverflow. Can you post links to minimal but complete samples illustrating the problem?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have the time to download, install and check stuff locally here, maybe someone else reading is willing to do it. You might want to ask in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/threads as an alternative to looking for help here although in any case your chances to find help are higher if you have URLs others can visit directly with the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I posted there the same time I made this post, and I haven't had any responses there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to specify the UTF-8 character set when converting xml to html.  I had to add this tag to the top of my XSL files.

`<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>`

In some files, `<xsl:output method="html" />` existed, but adding the encoding fixed the problem.